# How to read text off a website using python (Simple explanation)

Tags: python, html

I'm looking to make a program that can get the text off a website when given the website's URL. I would like to be able to get all text between the

tags. Everywhere I have looked online seems to overcomplicate this and it involves some coding in C which I am not well versed in. To summarize what I would like the code to look like (best case scenario). If theres anything I can clarify or is unclear in the question please let me know in comments

```
import WebReader as WR

StringOfWebText = WR.getParagrahText("WebsiteURL")
```

Comment: you might want to look at scapper/crawler like `beautifulsoup`

Comment: This shouldn't be too complicated, actually: two options are bs4 (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). If you have a *specific* programming problem, you could edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: The beautiful soup looks like the way to go once I have a websites HTML but how can I get the websites HTML into python using the URL

Comment: One thing of note is that if you want to get data from a website that loads from JavaScript you will need to use something that allows the JavaScript to load, like selenium

Comment: Thanks. For now I don't need that but will keep it in mind

Comment: Questions "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" are off-topic for StackOverflow. And if you're asking how to do it in Python, your question is too broad, opinion based and needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also a good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to look into something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) paired with [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). You can then extract text from a page with a simple solution like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.text)
```

There's also tag-searching and other useful features built into BS4, if you need to be able to handle that.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the answer I have been looking for ages. Perfect and concise

Comment: @MaxVK No problem ^-^ glad it was helpful. Something to note about this approach, though, might include the fact that your looked-for data could be far down in the website's tree, which means that you may have to convert to a tag-search basis, but that isn't incredibly difficult with bs4, you just pass the name of the tag into `.find()`.

Comment: Just wanted to point out the obvious, that the last line should read `print(soup.text)`, **not** `print(s.text)`